.../civicrm/login not found after civicrm standalone installation
I have tried to install civicrm standalone on a Ubuntu server VPS. Both STABLE and RC.
Installation run OK (in STABLE version, "core" folder has to be moved from "web" to root).
In both cases when I go to url after installation, I have "404 Not found" on url .../civicrm/login.
I find no "civicrm/login" in folders.
With NIGHTLY version, the not found url has "civicrm/home".

Do you perchance use nginx?
I ran into the same issue. Hope this below helps.
The .htaccess was of course not used (which was generated by the Civi CRM installer)
Chat GPT had a try at rewriting it for use in an nginx config.
Also I use let's encrypt, on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
Here is my config, "YOUR_DOMAIN" is inserted, the rest readable:
server {

root /var/www/YOUR_DOMAIN/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name YOUR_DOMAIN;

# Deny access to sensitive files
location ~ \.(inc|info|test|mo|po|sh|sql|tpl|tpl\.php)$ {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to backup and temporary files (including backup PHP files)
location ~ (\~|\.swp|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to files and directories starting with a dot (except .well-known)
location ~ (^|/)\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}

# Main location block for handling requests
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# PHP FastCGI handling
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;  # Pass HTTP Authorization header
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

# Deny access to .htaccess files (if any)
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# Error handling for 404 (redirect to index.php)
error_page 404 /index.php;

# Caching for static files (images, CSS, JS, etc.)
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|svg)$ {
    expires 2w;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Extra security headers
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

# SSL configuration (managed by Certbot)
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
if ($host = YOUR_DOMAIN) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name YOUR_DOMAIN;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

